# Discrete Fourier Transform, speed up calculation

Tags: python, dft

**Input:** hermitian matrix `\rho_{i,j}` with `i,j=0,1,..d-1`

**Output:** `neg=\sum |W(mu,m)|-W(mu,m)`, the sum over all `mu,m=0,..d-1` and
 `W(mu,m)=\sum exp(-4i\pi mu n /d) \rho_{(m-n)%d,(m+n)%d}`, where `n=0,..d-1`

**Problem:** 1) for large `d` (d>5 000) a direct method (see snippet 1) is rather slow.

2) making use of 'np.fft.fft()' is much faster, but in the definition exponent with 2 is used rather than 4 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#module-numpy.fft

Is it possible to improve snippet 1 using snippet 2 to boost speed calculation? May be one can use 2D fft?

**Snippet 1:**

```
W=np.zeros([d,d])
neg=0
        for mu in range(d):
            for m in range(d):
                x=0            
                for n in range(d): 
                    x+=np.exp(-4*np.pi*1.0j*mu*n/N)*rho[(m-n)%d,(m+n)%d]
                W[mu,m]=x.real
                neg+=np.abs(W[mu,m])-W[mu,m]
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
# create matrix \rho
psi=np.random.rand(500)
psi=psi/np.linalg.norm(psi) # normalize it
d=len(psi) 
rho=np.outer(psi,np.conj(psi)) 

#
start_time=time.time()
m=1 # for example, use particular m 

a=np.array([rho[(m-nn)%d,(m+nn)%d] for nn in range(d)])
ft=np.fft.fft(a)

end_time=time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the nested loops by exploiting `numpy`s array arithmetics.

```
import numpy as np

def my_sins(x):
    return np.sin(2*x) + np.cos(4*x) + np.sin(3*x)

def dft(x, n=None):
    if n is None:
        n = len(x)   
    k = len(x)    
    cn = np.sum(x*np.exp(-2*np.pi*1j*np.outer(np.arange(k),np.arange(n))/n),1)
    return cn
```

For some sample data

```
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000)
y = my_sins(x)

%timeit dft(y)
```

On my system this yields:

```
145 ms ± 953 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```